# MVC Dropdownlists - How to Set Dummy Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, drop-down-menu

This is kind of a two parter:

1)  **Where should I be feeding my DDL's from?**  Right now I have List set in my viewmodel.  I've seen a lot of people set the lists in the ViewData[]. Is that what I should be doing, and why?

I've noticed that the DDL values are not retained in the HttpPost and I have to reset them in the view model.  If I use ViewData[] I am assuming this is not necessary?

2) I am populating my DDL's from LinqToSQL by

`new SelectList(dataContext.Products.ToList(),"ID","Name");`

**How should I add a dummy field like "--Select a Product--" val="-1"?**

Comment: You will always have to recreate the drop down list values. Only the selected form values are posted to the server. ViewData[] is lost once the view is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a huge variety of methods to deal with drop down list data. I personally use filters to inject collections into view models (90% of the time at least), but I won't go into that there. You can use the Insert method to add a placeholder item.

```
var options = dataContext.Products.Select(p => new OptionItem(p.Id, p.Name)).ToList();
options.Insert(0, new OptionItem(-1, "--Select a Product--"));
// now use the options collection for the drop down list source
```

Note I did a projection from Product to OptionItem because you don't really need to query for the entire Product object if you just want two fields.